# Need a sed or perl command to replace line that starts with certain text

Tags: linux, sed, perl, solaris

I am looking for either sed or perl command to find a line in a file on multiple servers that begins with certain text and then replace the entire line. These lines will always start with the same string, but the rest may be different. So I need something that rather matches the beginning, and then replaces everything.

e.g.

**Server 1: My file.txt**

```
SAMail: root@root.com
```

**Server 2: My file.txt**

```
SAMail: none@none.com
```

**Server 3: My file.txt**

```
SAMail: help@help.com
```

I need a command that finds "SAMail:" in My `file.txt` on all three servers and replaces with `SAMail: test@test.com`

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possiblity with `sed` if I understand you correctly:

Input

```
SAMail: none@none.com
foo: foo@foo.com
foo SAMail
```

---

```
sed '/^SAMail/s;[^ ]*$;test@test.com;' "My file.txt"
```

---

Output:

```
SAMail: test@test.com 
foo: foo@foo.com
foo SAMail
```

Comment: This works to a degree.  However, any line with SAMail is changed. Needs to only count for those lines that start with SAMail

Comment: Mmmh that's what the `^` is for. Only the lines that *start* with SAMail are parsed.

Comment: Yes, I am understand that. But its still wiping out line that contain that string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by wipe?

Comment: Sorry, wiping out, erasing or changing.

Comment: Can you please explain what [^ ]*$ does? Looks like a pattern matching command, but I am not sure how it works. Thanks

Comment: Now you make me wonder... I understand that the strings that follow SAMail are in the form `test@test.com`, an email, always... but could be any string with spaces in it? If so my command is wrong (I was following the examples you gave).